# A zero-dimensional local ring that is not a tensor product of two zero-dimensional local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

Does there exist a commutative unital local ring $R$ of Krull dimension $0$ such that for any two commutative unital local rings $R_1$, $R_2$ of Krull dimension $0$ we have $R\not \approx R_1\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R_2$?

Comment: The answer is no. What have you tried?

Comment: @Mohan prime fields

Comment: When you say prime fields, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Mohan I mean I tried to prove that for $k$ a field containing no proper subfields, this is true (but it is not true).

Comment: For any field $k$, use $k_1=k$ and $k_2=\mathbb{Q}$ if characteristic zero or $\mathbb{F}_p$ if characteristic is $p>0$.